# I have error on fultter firebase core package

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, flutter-web, flutter-test

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':firebase_core:generateDebugRFile'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':firebase_core:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-common:.
> Required by:
> project :firebase_core

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.